# My NIC speed is 1g per second why scp speed is 120MB per second

Tags: linux, scp

My Network Interface card r/w rate is 1000MB/S, but when I scp one file it shows the copy speed is 120MB/S. such as: `scp test.gz localhost:/data/test.gz`

Comment: Aren't you confusing Mb/s (mega**bit** per second, see the lowercase 'b') with MB/s (mega**byte** per second)? 1000 Mb/s would be about 125MB/s which is quite compatible with the speed you see.

Comment: I'd like to add that I don't believe there are many 8Gb NIC's out there...

Comment: `scp` is simple and has small buffers. The speed differs with the latency of the link. If you want performance, use `sftp`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you're confusing M**b**/s (mega**bit** per second) with M**B**/s (mega**byte** per second).

1000 M**b**/s becomes a theoretical 125 M**B**/s, and 120 M**B**/s looks like good performance (since you don't give more information, I take that it is a standard desktop PC with SATA hard disks).

Besides, I don't really think you can reach 1 G**B**/s (which would mean 8 G**b**/s) without special equipment (10 Gb ethernet, a high-end NAS or a SAN etc...).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of scp, sometimes scp will fail if the file size is huge due to connection timeout issues.
Then You can try **rsync** command with bandwidth limit.
(Here bwlimit=2048 refers to 2GB/second transfer speed, you can change the limit as per your  from source to destination limit)

```
rsync -varP --bwlimit=2048 /tmp/localfile username@172.X.X.X
```

Comment: `--bwlimit` is a value in kilobytes per second, not megabytes, so 2048 would be 2MBps. Besides, this does not seem to answer the question.

Comment: @tomasz -- Yes typo, it's kilobytes per second. rsync is a suggestion instead of scp, in scp do we have bandwith limit. so I suggested to use rsync with 1gb bandwidth limit as per the above question

Answer (score -1):

`scp` is limited not just by your network interface speed (and indeed if you're using `localhost`, you're not even touching your network card), but also by disk I/O speed, CPU speed, and other mitigating factors.

Comment: I tried copy to other server instead of localhost, but two server in the same switch, the speed is still about 120MB/S. I don't think the disk I/O limited the speed.

Comment: A better test of raw network throughput is to a test that doesn't also do compression encryption, and a whole host of other things.  For example, you can  run `nc -l 22222` on one host, and `cat /dev/random | pv | nc host.example.com 22222` on the other.

Comment: @Jack if localhost is limited to 120mb/s, why would a remote host go faster? In other words, lets say your disk goes 10kbps, why would scp to a remote host go faster than 10kbps? Also DopeGhoti mentioned that the bottleneck could be something other than disk, such as CPU.

Comment: @DopeGhoti `/dev/random` is a bad source of data when you're trying to measure speed. `/dev/random` is abysmally slow.

Comment: `/dev/zero` would do nicely.  `urandom` is what I meant (which does not wait for more entropy), but the edit timer froze my comment before I could correct the error.